# Trace/wrap open system call

Tags: c, gcc, system-calls

I have the following test code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    fprintf(stderr, "This is a test.\n");
    int ret = open("somefile.log", 1);
    fprintf(stderr, "Return value is %d.\n", ret);
    return 0;
}
```

Compiled with `gcc -m64 test.c -o test`

If I run `truss ./test`, I eventaully see the following output:

```
getrlimit(RLIMIT_STACK, 0xFFFFFFFF7FFFE280)     = 0
getpid()                                        = 1984 [1983]
setustack(0xFFFFFFFF7EE002C0)
fstat(2, 0xFFFFFFFF7FFFDAA0)                    = 0
This is a test.
write(2, " T h i s   i s   a   t e".., 16)      = 16
open("somefile.log", O_WRONLY)                  = 3
Return value is write(2, " R e t u r n   v a l u e".., 16)      = 16
3.
write(2, " 3 .\n", 3)                           = 3
_exit(0)
```

I would like to hook the open system call and execute some code before the call to open finishes.  I have read about using ptrace to do this, however I do not have sys/ptrace.h on this system (solaris).  I see documentation stating that /proc debugging interfaces should be used instead of ptrace(), but I haven't been able to figure out how to do what I want using procfs.

Does anyone know if this is possible?  If so, how?

As a side note, I have also tried using the LD_PRELOAD trick to implement the open system call in my own shared library and have it call dlsym to find the address of the regular open system call.  I wasn't able to figure out 100% why this doesn't work, but it seemed related to the calls being inlined and not using an address table to lookup those functions.  However somehow `truss` is able to detect calls to open().

This was my code for that attempt:

`cat wrap_open.c`

```
#define _GNU_SOURCE

#include <dlfcn.h>
#include <stdio.h>

static int (*next_open) (const char *path, int oflag, /* mode_t mode */) = NULL;

int open(const char *path, int oflag)
{
    char *msg;

    if(next_open == NULL) {

            fprintf(stderr, "wrapping open\n");

            next_open = dlsym(RTLD_NEXT, "open");

            if((msg = dlerror()) != NULL) {
                    fprintf(stderr, "open: dlopen failed: %s\n", msg);
            } else {
                    fprintf(stderr, "open: wrapping done\n");
            }

    }

    fprintf(stderr, "open: opening %s\n", msg);
    fflush(stderr);

    return next_open(path, oflag);
}
```

Compiled with `gcc -fPIC -shared -Wl,-soname,libwrap_open.so.1 -ldl -o libwrap_open.so.1.0`
Executed with `LD_PRELOAD_32=./libwrap_open.so.1.0 ./test`

I don't get any output from the shared library here.  Only normal program output.

Any help or pointers is appreciated.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your attempt with LD_PRELOAD might have failed because the name of the libc function could be different (not `open()`). With truss option -u, you can trace the libc.so function calls as well, and see which libc function is used.

Comment: I tried this and get some lines looking like

Comment: `/1@1:   -> libc:open(0x10a50, 0x1, 0x0, 0xa13c8)`

`/1@1:     -> libc:_save_nv_regs(0xff362c40, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0)
/1@1:     <- libc:_save_nv_regs() = 0xff362c40
/1@1:     -> libc:_ti_bind_guard(0x1, 0x0, 0x1, 0xff3fa984)
...
/1@1:     -> libc:_open(0x10a50, 0x1, 0x0, 0x0)
/1@1:       -> libc:__open(0x10a50, 0x1, 0x0, 0x0)
/1:     open("somefile.log", O_WRONLY)                  = 3
/1@1:       <- libc:__open() = 3
/1@1:     <- libc:_open() = 3`

I'm having trouble figuring out what the name is.  Would it be open(char* a, char* b, char* c, char* d) ?

Comment: Actually, if I look at libc code for open I see:

libc_hidden_def (__libc_open)
weak_alias (__libc_open, __open)
libc_hidden_weak (__open)
weak_alias (__libc_open, open)

From googling around it sounds like these macros bypass the PLT, which is why I can't use LD_PRELOAD for these functions. I'll keep looking...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My error was stupider than you can imagine.

This was my command to compile

```
gcc -g -m64 -fPIC -shared -ldl -o libwrap_open64.so.1.0
```

This is the correct command

```
gcc -g -m64 -fPIC -shared -ldl -o libwrap_open64.so.1.0 wrap_open.c
```

I guess the first command builds a library with nothing in it.  I found the problem by running `nm -g libwrap_open64.so.1.0` and saw that my functions weren't being exported.  A bit of stratching my head before I realized I wasn't even compiling my code......